# Long URLs reported in Google Webmaster Tools that have http%252525 in the query string

Tags: google-search-console, url

Webmaster Tools finds around 30 pages with duplicate title. URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/9-modele-lumanari-de-botez?http%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253A%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fdesign-floral_ro%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252F9-modele-lumanari-de-botez%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253Fp%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D2=&p=4
```

And the original URL is `http://example.com/9-modele-lumanari-de-botez?p=4`.

All 30 URLs open the same page.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This looks to me to be a vulnerability test. While I do not know the specific vulnerability, it seems to be targeted to a single vulnerability. If they result in a 202 or 404 result code, you should be okay. You may want to block access by IP address. You will likely find that it is not a user block so no users will actually be blocked.

Comment: I what section of Webmaster Tools is this appearing?  Are you seeing this in the crawl error reports?  Is this in the duplicate page titles report?

Comment: Also, are you currently using meta canonical URL tags?   Doing so should solve the problem if you haven't already tried it.

Comment: Yes, is only in the duplicate page titles report. All the links work and lead to category page. Should I use a module for meta canonical URL tags ? I use PrestaShop 1.6